# IMG_Load; png unsupported image format

Tags: c

I'm currently trying to follow along Thomas Lively's seminar on learning to use SDL ([found here](https://youtu.be/yFLa3ln16w0)). However, whenever I attempt to run my code, I always get the error:

`Unsupported image format`

I have tried including `png.h` and `zlib.h` but they didn't fix the error, and I'm fairly certain it's pathed correctly. Compiling it returns zero errors.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "SDL2/SDL.h"
#include "SDL2/SDL_image.h"

int main() 
{
    SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO); 

    SDL_Window* win = SDL_CreateWindow("test", 
                                        SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED,
                                        SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED,
                                        640, 480, 0);

    Uint32 render_flags = SDL_RENDERER_ACCELERATED;
    SDL_Renderer* rend = SDL_CreateRenderer(win, -1, render_flags);
    SDL_Surface* surf = IMG_Load("Workspace/learnSDL/red.png");
    if (!surf)
    {
        printf("%s\n", IMG_GetError());
    }

    SDL_Texture* tex = SDL_CreateTextureFromSurface(rend, surf);

    SDL_Delay(10000);
    SDL_DestroyTexture(tex);
    SDL_DestroyRenderer(rend);
    SDL_DestroyWindow(win);
    SDL_Quit();
}
```

Comment: Have you copied `SDL_image.dll` to your .exe folder?

Comment: @usr2564301Thanks, I'll do that now

Comment: @SurvivalMachine No I haven't, I'll do that now. Should I change my header?

Comment: @ThomasLiang I meant just copy the file into your running directory, no source code modifications needed.

Comment: @SurvivalMachine That's odd. . . I can't find it by searching for it

Comment: Oh, you're probably using Linux or mac, so disregard my comment.

Comment: @SurvivalMachine Yes, I'm on Ubuntu at the moment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for everyone else' assistance, I managed to solve it by changing my makefile to include `-lSDL2_image`.

Answer (score 1):

You have to provide the path without `~`, eg. `/home/thomas/Workspace/learnSDL/red.png`

`~` is expanded by the shell, you can't use it like that on your own program.

On Windows you also need to have `SDL_image.dll`, libpng and zlib DLLs in your running directory.

Comment: That doesn't help. Unfortunately I still get the same error.

Answer (score 0):

While calling `IMG_Init()` should be optional, you can use it to check that the image format loading has been registered properly. Could be something wrong with your SDL installation and the program not finding `libpng`.

https://www.libsdl.org/projects/SDL_image/docs/SDL_image_8.html

Comment: I added a `IMG_INIT(IMG_INIT_PNG);` to the code but I still get the same error. Should I try reinstalling SDL_Image?